# Error Number: 1064 CodeIgniter query builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb, codeigniter-3

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND `instrument`.`type` = 2 ORDER BY `instrument`.`price` DESC LIMIT 100' at line 6

```
SELECT 
    `instrument`.`id` as `id`, 
    `instrument`.`name` as `name`, 
    `price`, 
    `isix`, 
    `wkn`, 
    `isin`, 
    `instrument`.`account` as `accID`, 
    `own_invest`, 
    `interest`, 
    (select company 
        from chart_of_accounts 
        where chart_of_accounts.id = accID 
        group by company
    ) as company_id, 
    (select url 
        from company 
        where company.id = company_id
    ) as company_url, 
    `tiv_bond_type`.`name` as `bond_type` 
FROM 
    `instrument` 
LEFT JOIN `bond` ON `bond`.`instrument` = `instrument`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `tiv_bond_type` ON `tiv_bond_type`.`bond_type` = `bond`.`type` 
WHERE 
    ( ) AND 
    `instrument`.`type` = 2 
ORDER BY 
    `instrument`.`price` DESC LIMIT 100
```

Filename: models/Search_model.php

Line Number: 251

```
public function search_bonds($name, $isin, $isix, $wkn, $type, $initial_price, $end_price, $initial_interest, $end_interest) {
        $bond_name = explode(" ", $name);

        $this->db->select("instrument.id as id, instrument.name as name, price, isix, wkn, isin, instrument.account as accID, own_invest, interest,
                            (select company from chart_of_accounts where chart_of_accounts.id = accID group by company) as company_id,
                            (select url from company where company.id = company_id) as company_url,
                            tiv_bond_type.name as bond_type");
        $this->db->from("instrument");
        $this->db->join("bond", "bond.instrument = instrument.id", "left", "outer");
        $this->db->join("tiv_bond_type", "tiv_bond_type.bond_type = bond.type", "left");
        if (strlen($isin) > 3)
            $this->db->where("instrument.isin", $isin);

        if (strlen($name) > 1) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->create_search_permutations($bond_name, 1);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }

        if (strlen($isix))
            $this->db->where("instrument.isix", $isix);

        if (strlen($wkn) > 3 )
            $this->db->where("instrument.wkn", $wkn);

        if (strlen($type) && is_numeric($type))
            $this->db->where('bond.type', $type);

        if (is_numeric($initial_price) && is_numeric($end_price)) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->where("instrument.price >= ", $initial_price);
            $this->db->where("instrument.price <= ", $end_price);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        else if (is_numeric($initial_price) && ! is_numeric($end_price))
            $this->db->where("instrument.price >= ", $initial_price);
        else if (is_numeric($end_price)  && ! is_numeric($initial_price))
            $this->db->where("instrument.price <= ", $end_price);

        if (is_numeric($initial_interest) && is_numeric($end_interest)) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->where("bond.interest >= ", $initial_interest);
            $this->db->where("bond.interest <= ", $end_interest);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        else if (is_numeric($initial_interest) && ! is_numeric($end_interest))
            $this->db->where("bond.interest >= ", $initial_interest);
        else if (is_numeric($end_price)  && ! is_numeric($initial_interest))
            $this->db->where("bond.interest <= ", $end_interest);
        $this->db->where("instrument.type", 2);
        $this->db->order_by("instrument.price", "desc");
        $this->db->limit(100);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

        private function create_search_permutations($search_array, $table_name, $permutations = array()) {
        /*
            $query_type variable is defining the type of table column the query string is targeting
            ie $query_type == 1 defines that the query string is for instrument.name and $query_type == 2 is for company.name
        */
        if (empty($search_array)) {
            if ($table_name == 'instrument')
                $this->db->or_where("instrument.name like '%".join('%', $permutations)."%'");
            elseif ($table_name == 'company')
                $this->db->or_where("company.name like '%".join('%', $permutations)."%'");
            else
                return;
        }
        else {
            for ($iterator = count($search_array) - 1; $iterator >= 0; --$iterator) {
                $new_search_array = $search_array;
                $new_permutations = $permutations;
                list($key) = array_splice($new_search_array, $iterator, 1);
                array_unshift($new_permutations, $key);
                $this->create_search_permutations($new_search_array, $table_name, $new_permutations);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone to helping with figuring out what is wrong with my code here.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the problem is with the `create_search_permutations` method. That method is wrapped in a `group_start`/`group_end` pair, but doesn't actually do anything to the query.

Comment: So what suggestion do you about this method should it be removed or if you were to solve this error what would you do.

Comment: i think this is exactly where the problem is... the `group_start` and `group_end` are adding the open and close parens to the SQL text. And the generated SQL is not valid, ie.  `... WHERE ( ) AND ...` is not valid.   As far as fixing the code, remove those calls.   `create_search_permutations` should be responsible for adding opening and closing parens if they are required, and not add parens if nothing is being added to the SQL text.

Comment: True i belive this is the cause can please clarify on how i would add group_start and group_end in the create_search_permutations method or i should remove them completely